# How can i reset the path of file uploaded in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating one function for uploading details with photos of users,
so for that i have use angularjs,
Their are multiple users i have to update from that page.

in that first user image get added successfully, but when i'm going to add next user image or update other data the path and name of image is by default shown up for next user.

[image]

like the above image

if i don't want to add image but do some other updates related to user and save them 
that time that image is also get send as it get auto selected,
could you please give me solution for this, 
i'm pretty new to UI part so i'm able to figur it out what is going wrong

```
    <form id="user-image-form" class="col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Select profile image</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-md fa-fw"></i></span>
                <input type="file" class="btn btn-default" id="imageFile" ng-model="imageFile"  name="imageFile" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadAndReloadImage()" style="width:100%">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Angular part

```
 $scope.uploadAndReloadImage = finction(){
         var FD  = new FormData();
         FD.append('image',document.getElementById("user-image-form"));
         d.image_file =  $scope.user_data.user_id;
        d.image_file_data = FD;
        var f = document.getElementById('imageFile').files[0];            
        if(f && $scope.user_data.user_id && $scope.user_data.user_id != "-1" && $scope.user_data.user_id != "")  {
        //ajax call
        }

       };
```

Comment: This is not the *Angular way*...

Comment: actually i have added this part not whole file, this part only how i have access the image file from html and did the ajax call